# Ionic storage - tables with key-value pairs?

Tags: sqlite, typescript, ionic-framework, storage

Is there a way to use something like tables combined with key value pairs in ionic 2+?

Explanation: I know ionic supports sqlite, but I don't need actual sql queries nor table structures. However the key-value pairs quickly hit a dead end. 
For example if I have records of posts, all with unique ids (e.g. uuid), I could save every post as key-value like

```
let posts = [post1,post2,post3]
posts.foreEach(post=>{
  this.storage.set(post.id,post)
})
```

However then I cannot retrieve the posts, because I don't know their ids.

Alternatively I could store the whole array like

```
let posts = [post1,post2,post3]
this.storage.set("posts",posts)
```

However then I cannot add, remove or edit a single post without first loading and then saving the whole array again. Especially with a lot of entries the rewriting becomes quite slow as I noticed.

It would be nice to have the option to group the key-value pairs into something like a table. Any chance to do so without using actual sql commands a la CREATE TABLE...?

I've seen the storage offers the option to create different instances, but unsure whether this fits the purpouse.

Comment: In approach 1, why can't you also save the keys in an array and store it?

Comment: @Ari that would be possible, yes. But it does not seem very straight forward, if you add/remove a post, because once again you have to retreive and store the whole keys array. Maybe there is a better option?

Comment: You could try and create a more efficient data structure for keys, but that's what a database does. So looks like what you need is sqlite or an online database like firebase, otherwise, it seems to me that you will have to create your own light database